# How to pipenv install djangorestframework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows, django-rest-framework, pipenv

My environment: Windows10 64, Python 3.7, Django 2.2
IDE: Visual Studio Code

I setup a virtual environment and activated it.
I am then trying to install djangorestframework with the command

```
pipenv install djangorestframework
```

Error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1074: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/djangorestframework/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement djangorestframework
ERROR: No matching distribution found for djangorestframework
```

Here is what I have installed in my env.

```
python -m pip list

Package             Version
------------------- -------
astroid             2.4.2
colorama            0.4.4
Django              2.2
isort               5.6.4
lazy-object-proxy   1.4.3
mccabe              0.6.1
pip                 20.3
pylint              2.6.0
pylint-django       2.3.0
pylint-plugin-utils 0.6
pytz                2020.4
setuptools          50.3.2
six                 1.15.0
sqlparse            0.4.1
toml                0.10.2
typed-ast           1.4.1
wheel               0.35.1
wrapt               1.12.1
```

When I tried

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

it worked.

What did I miss in my virtual environment?

Please help me install this package.

Answer (score -1):

try upgrading your pip type

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: I have pip==20.3.3, that's the latest. No, it is not working. Cannot install djangorestframework on Env.

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```
pipenv install rest_framework
```

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

According to this link: https://dev.to/habibaudu/simple-rest-api-with-django-rest-framework-4bmc

You can install django-rest-framework using pipenv using this:
`pipenv install djangorestframework`

Then you should add the django-rest-framework to the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file.

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'django.contrib.admin', 'rest_framework', ]`